# column index in splited dataindex variable

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I have a dataframe like df

```
ID  years   note    statut
1   0       16       8
7   0       1       4
…
2   2       2      5
3   2       8      4
…
```

I want 1 df in years in ouput

```
df0
ID  years   note0   statut0
1   0   16  8
7   0   1   4

df2
ID  years   note2   statut2
2   2   2   5
3   2   8   4
```

My code is

```
   liste <- list(1,2,3,4,5) 
    for (i in seq_along(liste)){   
       df[[i]] <- df %>%
          filter(years==i) %>%
          renames(note[[i]]=note) 
    }
```

but I have an error like:  Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i,....

It's possible to split by years but how to index columns

```
split(df, df$years)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `split(df, ~ years)`

Comment: Split is ok but rename note in note0 note1note2...... according to the  years